# Getting absolute path in C#

Tags: c#, filepath

I know that this question was answered many times and the solution that I have works almost in all cases except for one.

The code in question is this:

```
Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(rootFolder, relativeFilePath))
```

It works great most of the time even with messy relative paths, UNC and absolute paths as shown below:

```
// These results are OK
Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(@"a:\b\c", @"e.txt"));    // Returns: "a:\b\c\e.txt"
Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(@"a:\b\c", @"..\e.txt")); // Returns: "a:\b\e.txt" 
Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(@"a:\b\c", @"d:\e.txt")); // Returns: "d:\e.txt"
```

However in this case it does not work as expected:

```
Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(@"a:\b\c", @"\e.txt"))
```

Expected result is "a:\e.txt" but the code returns "c:\e.txt". "c:" is the current drive so it solves the part of the puzzle but why is this happening? Is there another way to get the full path that works in all cases?

**Edit:** Based on info from answers here is the solution that works. May need some null checking and alternative directory separator char checking though:

```
var rootDir = @"a:\b\c";
var filePath = @"\e.txt";
var result = (Path.IsPathRooted(filePath) && 
    Path.GetPathRoot(filePath) == Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString()) ?
    Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Path.GetPathRoot(rootDir), filePath.Substring(1))) :
    Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(rootDir, filePath));
```

Comment: Referred answer does not make much sense. It suggests removing leading slash which produces completely different result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As written in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If path2 includes a root, path2 is returned.

The fact that `path2` begins with slash makes it a root.

Also, in [Path.GetFullPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This method uses current directory and current volume information to fully qualify path. If you specify a file name only in path, GetFullPath returns the fully qualified path of the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation:

> If path2 includes a root, path2 is returned.

Looking at the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/path.cs) we can see that if a path starts with a "\" then it is considered to contain a root.

```
// Tests if the given path contains a root. A path is considered rooted
// if it starts with a backslash ("\") or a drive letter and a colon (":").
//
[Pure]
public static bool IsPathRooted(String path) {
    if (path != null) {
        CheckInvalidPathChars(path);

        int length = path.Length;
        if ((length >= 1 && (path[0] == DirectorySeparatorChar || path[0] == AltDirectorySeparatorChar)) || (length >= 2 && path[1] == VolumeSeparatorChar))
             return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Looks like Boolean answer is just too simple for paths :) I would not consider \somepath rooted but then it could be the bug so old that it has become the feature.